# phpspreadsheet: cannot retrieve sources

Tags: composer-php, phpspreadsheet

Win11/WSL2: developing psf web program for writing xlsx spreadsheet based on data from pdf. (have earlier developed program in Perl, but my 'webserver does not really support perl ...

Am attempting to use PsfSpreadsheet.'composer require phpoffice/phpspreadsheet', Seems to work according to vendor directory. Tried to do 'composer require phpoffice/phpspreadsheet --prefer-source', but I have not gotten the 'sources' subdirectory. What to do? (also, how do I 'unrequire'  a previous require?

Comment: What kind of "sources subdirectory" are you looking for? Can you share the code you are currently using, and a proper problem statement?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.